# How to create a copy of a form with its DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

How does one create a copy of a form with all of its form elements so that the copy can be manipulated and the original is left unchanged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using plain javascript `cloneNode` like this

```
var dupNode = node.cloneNode(deep);
```

Example

```
var p = document.getElementById("para1"),
var p_prime = p.cloneNode(deep); 
//If "deep" is set to true it will clone all the child nodes too,
//If set to false then only the node and not the children
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is `deep` a valid argument?

Comment: @reformed Yes, `cloneNode` [accepts a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).

Comment: @reformed i have added a link to the docs .. this is plain js just as you wanted.

Comment: Would be nice if you could accept the answer and upvote it .. but only do it if it helped you :) Cheers @reformed .

Comment: @woofmeow I appreciate your help but it would be nice if you'd let me take time away from the computer for other personal things and also to wait for other answers. I already upvoted it, I was planning on accepting your answer. Are you a rep chaser?

Comment: I am not a "rep chaser" for whatever that mean but sometimes I just like to see if my answer helped the person who asked the question or not. You can even downvote it if you'd like @reformed I wouldn't care. Its just good at times to see a prompt reply. Feel free to downvote too. No issues with me. Have a nice day.

Comment: Just remember that some people aren't always able to give a prompt reply, due to work or whatever else. Asking for votes can be kind of annoying. You might want to take up politics if that's your thing ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use the jQuery clone object as such:

```
var cloned_object = $( ".hello" ).clone().
```

and to add it to the dom

```
cloned_object.appendTo( ".goodbye" );
```

Here is the reference:

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Thanks. Any equivalent in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object ... this has one

Comment: @Smurfette: No, that's about JavaScript objects in general, not DOM elements. Also from the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* Please keep that in mind.