# How to replace iframe document with another pre-existing document object, without using write()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, yui, domdocument

I just want to replace a blank iframe's document with a pre-existing document object. Not a string of HTML that can use the `write()` method with *(that solution is in many other answers, here)*. I just want a document object to replace another document.

**My blank iframe:**

`<iframe src="about:blank" id="myIframe"></iframe>`

**Routine to replace blank iframe document:**

```
function replaceIframeDoc(objDoc){
    var nod_if    = document.getElementById("myIframe");
    var nod_ifDoc = nod_if.contentWindow.document || nod_if.contentDocument;
    nod_ifDoc     = objDoc;
}
```

**Document object created, and call to do the replace:**
*(Note: I encapsulate my document object in a simple object... I need to do that for some other unrelated stuff... just to easily transfer some attributes, etc. Hopefully it's inconsequential to my issue!)*

```
var obj_container = new Object;  //just to make easier to do some other stuff
obj_container.document = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
obj_container.document.open();
obj_container.document.write("<html>...(some html)...</html>");
obj_container.document.close();
replaceIframeDoc(obj_container.document);
```

Comment: I think you could follow this idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196541/how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-form-with-its-dom-elements

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which browser you need to support, you could do something like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");;
var oldNode = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("myNode");
var newNode = document.importNode(oldNode, true);
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newNode);
```

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode

Comment: I need to primarily support webkit and safari.

`importNode()` seems like the best method... however, I'm not sure it's really suited for the document-level element, is it?